# I would like to ask if netbeans IDE is alright to use in GUI building?

Tags: ide, netbeans

is that alright for the programming industry? when you are using the 'auto generated codes' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say NetBeans is a pretty good tool for developing GUIs.  There is a lot of the UI of NetBeans that was developed using the NetBeans UI editor.  I just did a quick find to discover how many dot-form files are in the primary source repository for NetBeans.  I found 1925 files.  While some of these files are probably associated with dead code, you can see that the NB team has a large investment in using our tool to create our tool.

Answer (score 0):

Matisse - the SWING ui builder is one of the best in the industry right now. I am not sure about it's JSF experience though it did take over from Creator.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people love Matisse and it does make some visual tasks easier.

One big limitation though (IMHO) is that once you go down that road, you are tied to that editor.

What I mean by that is that since the UI information is in a (non java) form file, if you edit the UI java class using a different IDE, you can no longer edit the file in Netbeans.

So pick your UI IDE carefully, and stick with it.